# How to draw the heightmap onto the screen?

Tags: graphics, directx, simulation, directx-10

I'm using DirectX10 to simulate a water surface, and I'm now with a height map,which is a 2D array of the heights(y) at the points (x,z). But to draw it on the screen, I must turn it into a mesh or have a index to draw triangle topology.

But the data is too large to do it manually. Are there any methods for me to draw it on the screen. I hope it's easy to implement. If there is function included in DirectX10 which can make it, the it's the best one for me.

Comment: Emmm...When I said "too large", I meant I  couldn't type in the typology myself by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mesh that format a grid of squares (each made of two triangles) and set all vertices **y = 0**. In the vertex shader **sample the heightmap** and add the value stored in the heightmap to the **y of the vertice**.

[This might help you.](http://www.rastertek.com/tertut02.html)

P.S: If the area you want it to cover is too big you should take a look at terrain LOD techniques (should work the same for water).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can make a mesh out of it.  I doubt you can generate the heightmap for a water surface that is too large to "meshify".

Why are you looking at Diamond square.  For a 512x512 heightmap all you need to do is define a set of point and then generate the triangles for it.  Its really very simple.

Comment: I just found a method called the Diamond-Square method, which can generate heightmap. I have generate a 512 * 512 one. In fact you can get a larger one from that. But how can I mesh it ?